# Calculate Pearson correlation between two 2D datasets in Python

Tags: python, pearson-correlation

I have two data sets coming from .csv files, now as pandas dataframes:

Data set 1: **20 x 1000 (rows x column)**

Data set 2: **130 x 1000 (rows x column)**

Using Python, I would like to calculate Pearson correlation across all columns **between the two data sets**, so I end up with a **20 x 130 (rows x column)** matrix with correlation coefficients in the cells.

My goal is to see if there are corresponding clusters between the 20 and the 130 rows across all data in the 1000 columns.

```
df1.shape
```

(130, 1000)

```
df2.shape
```

(20, 1000)

My goal:

```
df_output.shape
```

(130, 20)

I have tried the following: I compute the correlation coefficient one cell at a time, thus computing Pearson-correlation between columns (1000).

```
s2 = df2.T.iloc[0,:]
s1 = df1.T.iloc[0,:]
s1.corr(s2, method='pearson')
```

Then I tried to loop through the rows of the matrices.

```
corlist = []
for j in range(20):
    s2 = df2.T.iloc[j,:]
    for i in range(130):
        s1 = df1.T.iloc[i,:]
    cor = s1.corr(s2, method='pearson')
    corlist.append(cor)
    #np.savetxt('')
```

Is there a more simple way to do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Hi Liz, unfortunately it is impossible from your question to see where you ran into a problem. Can you show us the code which you have so far so we can get a better understanding of what's going wrong?

Comment: This problem seems intractable. How exactly do you want the correlations to be computed? The number of rows of the two data sets are different, which otherwise is a requirement to calculate correlation among two variables/columns. Do you want to compute correlation between each col of dataframe 1 with each col of dataframe 2? If this is the case then the correlation matrix will be  of shape (1000, 1000).

Comment: Hi Liz, as @naive said it, correlation matrix have to be square.